# Como adicionar mais uma regra de exceção no Angular?

Tags: angular

Antes de mostrar o meu problema gostaria de informa que meu formulário está conseguindo inserir registros no banco, eu criei uma exceção na minha API java, a mensagem de erro na figura abaixo é esperado, porém meu projeto Angular está conseguindo somente emitir exceções genéricas, e preciso criar uma mensagem de erro para essa exceção abaixo e não sei como fazer.

Observe a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código responsável em pegar a exceção genérica, e é nesse código que deve modificar para conseguir gerar uma mensagem para a exceção especifica com o nome de **NomeEstiloJaCadastradoException**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';

@Injectable()
export class ErroHandlerService {

  constructor(private toasty: ToastyService) { }

  handle(errorResponse: any) {
    let msg: string;

    if (typeof errorResponse === 'string') {
      msg = errorResponse;
    } else {
      msg = 'Erro ao processar serviço remoto. Tente novamente.';
      console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);
    }

    this.toasty.error(msg);
  }

}
```

Eu sei que encontrei um modelo parecido com o meu na internet, porém não sei como realizar essa alteração para o sistema pegar a exceção de nome **NomeEstiloJaCadastradoException**, e preciso de ajuda

[Modelo](https://github.com/algaworks/curso-angular-rest-spring-boot-ui/blob/master/20.4-fazendo-deploy-em-producao-no-heroku/src/app/core/error-handler.service.ts)

[MEU REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/wladyband/controle-de-cervejas)

Comment: Uma pequena nota: erro de usuário já existente deveria retornar status 409.

Comment: eu não acredito que isso seja importante.

Comment: Porque isso seria importante?